# XSLT move node with a parent node into each parent's siblings that have a given attribute

Tags: xslt

I have the following source a.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="a">a
      <div class="a1">a1</div>
      <div class="x" type="typea2">x
        <div class="x1">x1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="a3">a3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="b">b_1
      <div class="b1">b1_1</div>
      <div class="b3">b3_11</div>
      <div class="b3">b3_12</div>
      <div class="b3">b3_13</div>
    </div>
    <div class="b">b_2
      <div class="b1">b1_2</div>
      <div class="b3">b3_21</div>
      <div class="b3">b3_22</div>
    <div class="b">b_3
      <div class="b1">b1_3</div>
      <div class="b3">b3_31</div>
      <div class="b3">b3_32</div>
      <div class="b3">b3_33</div>
      <div class="b3">b3_34</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want to:

1. copy the element div class="x" inside each div class="b" after its own text and any div class="b1"
2. remove the original div class="x" from div class="a"

The output should be:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="a">a
      <div class="a1">a1</div>
      <div class="a3">a3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="b">b_1
      <div class="b1">b1_1</div>
      <div class="x" type="typea2">x
        <div class="x1">x1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="b3">b3_11</div>
      <div class="b3">b3_12</div>
      <div class="b3">b3_13</div>
    </div>
    <div class="b">b_2
      <div class="b1">b1_2</div>
      <div class="x" type="typea2">x
        <div class="x1">x1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="b3">b3_21</div>
      <div class="b3">b3_22</div>
    <div class="b">b_3
      <div class="b1">b1_3</div>
      <div class="x" type="typea2">x
        <div class="x1">x1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="b3">b3_31</div>
      <div class="b3">b3_32</div>
      <div class="b3">b3_33</div>
      <div class="b3">b3_34</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have used the following shell script a.sh:

```
xsltproc --html a.xslt a.html > b.html
```

with the following a.xslt:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- ignore x-inside-a -->
 <xsl:template match="//div[@class='a']/div[@class='x']"/>

 <!-- place the x-inside-a into each b after text() and b1 -->
 <xsl:template match="div[@class='b']">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:copy-of select="//div[@class='a']/div[@class='x']" />
   <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However I am not getting the desired result?

Could I ask for your help please?

Comment: Is there always a `div class="b1"` in the `div class="b"`? Or where do you want to insert the other `div` if the `div class="b1"` is not there?

Comment: Hi Martin. Yes, div class="b1" is always present in div class="b".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the inner `div` is always present I would write a template for it:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*" name="identity">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <!-- ignore x-inside-a -->
 <xsl:template match="div[@class='a']/div[@class='x']"/>

 <!-- place the x-inside-a into each b after b1 -->
 <xsl:template match="div[@class='b']/div[@class = 'b1']">
  <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
  <xsl:copy-of select="//div[@class='a']/div[@class='x']" />
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```